# Perl command Performance issue

Tags: linux, shell, python, perl

I've used the following command to remove special characters in number columns (.CSV file) and it is working fine as excepted but the issue here is performance. My CSV file number column data contains as below. To remove 1000 separator comma in data I've used the following Perl command.

```
payment        
"4,326.34"        
590.20          
"12,499.40"
```

Note: My file delimiter was "," comma.

```
input file :               
    Organization,Amount,Revenue,Balance,Desc
    Congos,"4,233.78","3,233.78","1,233.78",Payment
    Toyoto,590.2,390.2,190.2,Payment
    lenives,"5,234.89","2,234.89","1,234.89",Payment
            
            
Excepted OutPut:                    
    Organization,Amount,Revenue,Balance,Desc
    Congos,4233.78,3233.78,1233.78,Payment
    Toyoto,590.2,390.2,190.2,Payment
    lenives,5234.89,2234.89,1234.89,Payment
```

***Command :***  `cat | perl -p -e 's/,(?=[\d,.]\d")//g and s/"(\d[\d,.])"/\1/g' 'test.csv' >> newfile.csv`

***File data count:*** 11 millions data

**Issue:** It was taking almost 10 minutes to remove 1000 separate "comma" in data.

Any better solution to improve performance?

Comment: Worth revising question to include short example of input file and associated 'desired output' file.

Comment: It is not the 1000 commas that slow it down, it is the 10,999,000 rows that don't have commas. It is processing (searching) 18,000 lines a second. Seems to me a quoted comma can only occur in a quoted field. I don't do Perl, but if you use an initial search for the first `"`, and just output lines without quote, and only invoke the complex REs if there is a quoted field, it should run several times faster.

Comment: Steve, revised my post. Now it looks more detailed mode. Let me know if you can give some hit or solution for my issue.

Comment: Paul, My files contain millions of data along with many number columns which contain a comma in the number field. I want to search each number column and find the string value and remove it as shown in the output file.

Comment: Are the number of columns as you show or they could be more? Can a record contain both a plain number col and quoted number col? Are all numbe columns double quoted or some could be single quoted too? Can quotes be inside columns? Can non number columns be quoted!.....

Comment: Your perl one-liner doesn't work.  It doesn't strip commas or quote characters from numbers even in the 4-line input sample you provided.  It doesn't do anything - the output is identical to the input.   Fix that first, using the small sample, before trying to optimise performance.

Comment: I completely understand the problem, but you said "Many number columns" ? I thought you originally said only 1000 separator columns to remove. They can't occur on more that 1000 different lines in total. So what proportion of lines actually needs to be fixed? I'm suggesting the Perq equivalent of `! index ($0, "\042") { print; next; }` (in awk) to avoid invoking those complex REs on lines that can't possibly be matched by them. I have got a 30x speed factor like this on files with a small proportion of difficult cases.

Answer (score 3):

I saved your sample input to a file, then copied the data rows several million times so that it had about 11 million records:

```
$ wc -l input2.csv 
11100445 input2.csv

$ ls -l input2.csv 
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 505070243 Apr 10 22:32 input2.csv
```

#### Quick & Dirty one-liner:

```
$ time perl -pe 's/"([0-9-.]+),?([0-9-.]+)"/$1$2/g' input2.csv >output.csv

real 0m37.922s  user 0m36.371s  sys 0m1.347s
```

This strips commas and quote (`"`) characters from numeric fields.  Unfortunately, it only works correctly for numeric fields with only a single comma in them - i.e. numbers below  `1,000,000`.   I decided it wasn't worth the effort to come up with a regex that would match multiple commas in a numeric field, instead I'd use a csv parsing library.

#### Slower, but more "correct" using the Text::CSV module

This version uses a CSV-parsing perl module, examines each field to see if it's numeric, and strips any commas if it is.   This works with numeric fields of any value.

It doesn't need to delete any quote characters around numeric fields - Text::CSV is handling field quoting automatically.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Text::CSV;

my $filename = shift;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
open my $fh, $filename or die "$filename: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    my @row = map { tr/,//d if ( m/^[0-9,.-]+$/); $_ } @{ $row };
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, \@row);
    print "\n";
}
close($fh);
```

Save this as, e.g., `strip.pl` and make it executable with `chmod +x strip.pl`.

```
$ time ./strip.pl input2.csv > output2.csv

real 1m32.379s  user 1m30.422s  sys 0m1.609s
```

This could probably be optimised a lot, I didn't expend any effort trying to make it faster - 1.5 minutes doesn't seem too bad for processing 11 million records and examining/modifying 5 fields in each record.

```
$ ls -l input2.csv output.csv output2.csv 
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 505070243 Apr 10 22:32 input2.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 430142246 Apr 10 22:40 output2.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 430142246 Apr 10 22:37 output.csv

$ cmp output.csv output2.csv 
$ echo $?
0
```

Both output files are identical, so it looks like your CSV file doesn't have any numeric fields with values >= 1 million. The quick-and dirty version should work.

#### Your Performance Issues

Your perl one-liner ran in about 15 seconds on my system (threadripper 1950x, 64GB RAM, 2xNVME SSDs in a zfs mirrored pair*), but it didn't do anything - the output was identical to the input.

I suspect your performance problems are due to a combination of one or more of:

- slow CPU
- slow hard disk
- and, most importantly, not enough RAM

In other words, there's probably not much you can do to improve performance by optimising the algorithm - at least not until you've made some major upgrades to your system.  If you ignore the fact that it doesn't work, your one-liner is almost 3 times faster than mine, and about 7 times faster than the Text::CSV version.

One thing that **might** significantly improve performance (if slow disk I/O is a major source of the problem, which it probably is) is to compress your CSV file with `gzip` and then `zcat` it into a working one-liner. It will probably compress down to under 10MB - *reading* < 10MB or so of data from disk will be ~ 50 times faster than *reading* 500MB or more.   `xz` and `xzcat` and similar compression programs would work as well, or better.

This doesn't mean that the entire process will run 50 times faster, just that reading the file will be much faster.  perl will still need to process each line individually.

---

* BTW, NVMEs are fast, but zfs is kind of slow (compared to simple filesystems like ext4 or xfs). OTOH lz4 compression is enabled which makes file reads fast again.

Comment: Hello Cas, Thanks a lot for spending a decent time on my post. Here are my outcomes based on your suggestion. 

Test Case1:
$ time perl -pe 's/"([0-9-.]+),?([0-9-.]+)"/$1$2/g' test.csv >output.csv

real    9m17.037s
user    6m33.230s
sys     0m32.939s

It took close to 10 minutes in my Linux box. yes, you right if the value is having more than two commas then a big challenge to choose this option.

Comment: Test Case 2: I've tried using Text::CSV option.
I've saved code into a strip.pl file and executed but no luck getting the following error.

time ./strip.pl /dir/test.csv > output2.csv
Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at ./strip.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./strip.pl line 3.

Comment: Text::CSV is a perl library module that you need to install.  If you're running debian or ubuntu or similar, `apt install libtext-csv-perl libtext-csv-xs-perl`.  Other Linux distros probably also have it packaged.  Otherwise, you can install it with `cpan`.     can also be found at https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV

Answer (score 0):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ in2csv file.csv
Organization,Amount,Revenue,Balance,Desc
Congos,4233.78,3233.78,1233.78,Payment
Toyoto,590.2,390.2,190.2,Payment
lenives,5234.89,2234.89,1234.89,Payment
```

The `in2csv` utility converts from various tabular data formats to CSV.  Converting your perfectly valid CSV file with `in2csv` makes it re-interpret the numbers in the `en_US` locale (by default), and removes the `,` in them.

The `csvkit` tools are built on top of a CSV parser implemented in Python.